# Could mathematical reasoning be non-axiomatic?

Tags: foundations, meta-math, automated-theorem-proving

"Mathematics is not a deductive science—that's a cliché. When you try to prove a theorem, you don't just list the hypotheses, and then start to reason. What you do is trial and error, experimentation, guesswork. You want to find out what the facts are, and what you do is in that respect similar to what a laboratory technician does."-Paul Halmos.

Following the argument of Paul Halmos, which I agree with, I don't think mathematics as done by mathematicians proceeds in an axiomatic manner. Now, I wonder whether we can provide foundations for mathematical reasoning as done by humans.

I think this might have relevance to automated theorem discovery or 'automated conjecturing' if such a field exists.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? If it's the one stated in the title you should expand on it a bit.

Comment: I agree with Halmos, but I don't think it follows that mathematics cannot be axiomatized.  In my view, mathematics only exists on an axiomatic foundation.  If it's not axiomatized, it's not mathematics.  Those axioms may change, but they still need to be there.  Mind you, I'm only an amateur, so I'd be interested to see what others have to say

Comment: @JasonM I clarified my question. But, I disagree that if mathematics isn't axiomatized then it isn't mathematics. Calculus done by Euler and his peer wasn't axiomatized but it was still done very well.

Comment: @mrf he probably forgot to add "?" at "... as done by humans". It's a very nice question though.

Comment: This is a bit meaningless. The process of designing architecture is different from the result of architecture. The process of programming is different from the result of programming. It's not clear what an "axiomization" of the processes would mean, but it is nearly a boring a statement to suggest that the human processes that go into most interesting endeavors are not axiomatizable.

Comment: @AidanRocke I think you are confusing the process with the product.

Comment: @almagest I've clarified my question. I think this might have relevance to automated theorem proving.

Comment: @AidanRocke They used very rough axiomatizations that were as good as they had.  They used (not entirely formal) rules about infinitesimals and assumptions like the Generality of Algebra.  We have since replaced them with better assumptions and axioms, but their arguments were fine for their time.

Comment: Math is an episode of Columbo. He knows who the murderer is in the first five minutes. He spends the rest of the show *proving* it.

Answer (score 4):

If I may quote Andres Caceido:

> Mathematical theories are rarely developed axiomatically from the
>   beginning. Instead, our axiomatizations tend to be the product of
>   hindsight, using the experience accumulated through examples, guess
>   work, and semi-rigorous reasoning.

This is true for almost all branches of mathematics:

1. Euclidean geometry: people were doing geometry long before Euclid's axiomatization of geometry
2. standard analysis: analysis originated from calculus which was done in an ad-hoc manner before Dedekind, Weierstrass, Cauchy and others tried to give it rigorous foundations.

Moreover, I'd like to say the following regarding axiomatisations:

1. Axiomatisations are not unique. Just look at the multiple axiomatisations of Euclidean geometry as an example.
2. Axiomatisations are necessary for proofs and they also help elucidate the structure of a mathematical theory so different theories can be compared.
3. Godel showed that the axiomatisation of any theory isn't sufficient to prove its consistency if it contains a theory of numbers.

It follows that mathematicians axiomatise branches of mathematics because of its practical value but many creative mathematicians(arguably the most creative) in history didn't use axioms as their starting point for the development of new mathematical objects. Think of Poincare and the birth of algebraic topology. Leibniz and the invention of Calculus. All of mathematical physics. ...etc.

Finally, I think that while the close analysis of a set of axioms can lead to many fruitful ideas a computer that aims to make mathematical discoveries should not be constrained by the set of axioms it's based on. Mistakes(guided by intuition) very often are fruitful, and the history of mathematics can offer plenty of examples.

I think it's for this reason that Poincare says:

> Pure analysis puts at our disposal a multitude of procedures whose
>   infallibility it guarantees; it opens to us a thousand different ways
>   on which we can embark in all confidence; we are assured of meeting
>   there no obstacles; but of all these ways, which will lead us most
>   promptly to our goal? Who shall tell us which to choose? We need a
>   faculty which makes us see the end from afar, and intuition is this
>   faculty. It is necessary to the explorer for choosing his route; it is
>   not less so to the one following his trail who wants to know why he
>   chose it.

References:

1. [Poincare on intuition in mathematics](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Poincare_Intuition.html)
2. [A fully automatic problem solver with human style output](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4501v1.pdf)

**Note:** As of this date most automated reasoning systems do brute force graph traversal over the grammar that defines the axioms of a particular system. Due to time and space constraints, this can't be the future of automated reasoning.

Comment: Non standard analysis was not created ab nihilo by a logican. In fact, non standard analysis was standard analysis for a long time. What logicians did was formalize it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I actually agree on that point. But, as far as I know infinitesimals were gradually abandoned until Robinson showed that they can be given solid foundations. Would you agree?

Comment: Sure. But that is precisely why your listing nonstandard analysis as an exception to what Andrés describes as s a process which tends «to be the product of hindsight, using the experience accumulated through examples, guess work, and semi-rigorous reasoning» is very wrong!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Point taken. I just edited my post.